# Statistical approach to quickly determine the volume of a complex figure

Tags: volume, surfaces, monte-carlo

I am looking to create an algorithm to determine the volume of a complex figure, that may not be complete (has gaps) through statistical methods, perhaps Monte Carlo?

Is such a thing possible? and is it a practical approach to calculating volumes?

EDIT

The complex figure is represented as a Triangulated Mesh

Comment: Monte Carlo can be quite slow, and in particular for 3D regions. I would start with a grid method, where I would define a regular grid and then determine if a grid cell is completely inside the volume ...

Comment: Depends on what representation you have of the complex figure. Is it an implicit surface, a parametric surface, a triangulated mesh, a point cloud, ...?

Comment: I've just finished working such a problem myself. In my case I develop the 3D regions as a function of (x,y,z) using a Matlab program I wrote. I then use a triangulated mesh program that I found in the Matlab User's group and it worked out quite well. You can also use this method to get the surface area. I was able to very the results over a broad variety of unconventional shapes.

Comment: @Rahul - thanks for your reply, I have edited my question.

Comment: @cyeWaldman would be interested in learning more if you were willing to share.

Comment: @pingu What I have to offer would only make sense if you use Matlab. Basically, I'm not familiar with triangulated surfaces so I got some programs from the Matlab User's group and figured out how to get the volume. It's still a work in progress and what I have now apparently works only for shapes that are symmetric about the $x-y$ plane. Let me know.